# Which database(s) to use when searching millions of records and forming connections?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, database-design, neo4j, database

I am working on a small project with a large, not-often changing, dataset of people. Each record is stored with a person's name and list of previous companies they worked for (by numbered ID).

I am writing a single-paged web application which lets you search and visually view the connections of people and companies. If I input "John Smith", it will show me the companies he worked for, the people working in that company, and the companies they worked for, and on and on (like a network graph).

I am currently using MongoDB to store all of these people... but I have a feeling that this isn't an optimal solution. I see that there are many different datastores such as Cassandra (wide-column), Couchbase (similar to Mongo?), ElasticSearch (searching), Neo4J (graph) which may be more optimal and provide better performance.

There are a huge amount of options to pick from, but I am unsure how to pick the most optimal solution to use.

Is it okay to use more than one database (e.g. MongoDB and Neo4J), or is this bad in practice as it's hard to keep them both synchronized together?

How do I go about picking the most optimal set of technologies to ensure that my application performs well and can query my dataset easily?

Answer (score 1):

While this question might be closed to be opinion-based, there are some points you need to take into account.

A) Updating a network into a normalized store (mongo for eg) is sometimes problematic, once you update one point of the network you end up having to update adjacent nodes and so multiple MongoDb documents.

Note that it is the same as well for Elasticsearch.

B) You mention "Search". In the mentioned technologies, there is only one real candidate there and it is Elasticsearch. While Neo4j has cool integrations like the widely used [neo4j-to-elasticsearch](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch) plugin or [APOC](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures), when you start to have some needs regarding the search then ES is one of the best technologies on the planet.

So IMO, take the best of both. Lot of big companies are doing it, Airbnb for eg (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gayXC2FDSiA)

What you'll get at the end is the ability to benefit from powerful search combined with graph based relevancy boosting.

A more complex example is what we call [Graph-Aided Search](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/20/graph-aided-search-the-rise-of-personalised-content.html).

Answer (score 0):

1) Interesting that you state that the structure is "like a network graph". So that kind of database would be an obvious fit.

2) Keeping several databases in sync is a pain, no doubt about it, but you do claim that your dataset is pretty static. So you can deal with the pain and choose the best match for each part of your problem. On the other hand ... solutions like Neo4j and MongoDB do have full-text search capabilities included (or easily implemented). Unless you require super-duper searching capabilities I don't think Elasticsearch is a candidate for your problem.

3) I would choose two likely candidates (and personally I'd go with Neo4j (graph) and stick with MongoDB (since you've already got your data in that format)) and do a POC. Can you answer your problem ? Is it flexible enough to answer different problems ?

Just my 2.5 eurocent opinion of course.

Regards,
Tom